# ExpandableListView inside SwipeRefreshLayout doesnt scroll properly

Tags: android, expandablelistview, swiperefreshlayout

The issue I am having is that the expandable list view is able to scroll down properly, but when I try scrolling up on the expandable list view, it starts the refresh. I am able to scroll up on the expandable list when it first swipe down, and then up again. I want to know if it is possible to only refresh the expandable list when they are at the top of the list or to properly scroll up. I know that a list view has a onScrollListener, so is there something similar to expandable lists? Any help or other suggestion are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
    expandableListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int topRowVerticalPosition = (expandableListView == null || expandableListView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : expandableListView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(firstVisibleItem == 0 && topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    boolean allow = false;

    if(visibleItemCount>0) {
        long packedPosition = elvMounters.getExpandableListPosition(firstVisibleItem);
        int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);
        int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition);
        allow = groupPosition==0 && childPosition==-1 && elv.getChildAt(0).getTop()==0;
    }

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(allow);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: how is that supposed to be used? where is onScroll??